# How to access one database from another database in Postgresql same as SQL Server?

Tags: postgresql

Reg - Postgresql cross database reference

We are currently using Postgres 14.5, where we are noticing some challenges with cross database reference.

*Note: Earlier, we were using SQL Server where the cross database reference was very simple.*

Everything was perfect until we handle the data of each customer separately but when we thought of consolidating the data(for EDW), we came to know that the cross database reference in Postgres is not as simple as SQL Server. We have to create **fdw** for each database(in the EDW database).

As the database count is less now, creating **fdw** for each database is not a big deal. But, when the customer count increase, the complexity will also increase(need to create **fdw** for each customer).

Moreover, if we want to make any schema modifications(such as increasing the length of the column), we have to make changes in all the fdw, which will make the setup even worse.

Now, we are thinking of rearchitecting the application to have a single database for all the client. But since, we are in Healthcare RCM business, data isolation is also a key point to be noted while handling data (shared database)

Can anyone suggest the best solutions for our requirement, out the below two.

1. Keep all the customer's data into single database and segregate them based on schema(one schema for each customer)
2. Our current setup - separate database for each customer

Additional question, why Postgres's cross database reference is so complex unlike SQL Server

Comment: As to _why_: because those two DBMS have a fundamentally different architecture. Cross-database queries in Oracle aren't fun either - again because of the completely different architecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put all the data in a single database, ideally in different schemas. You didn't have data isolation in SQL Server, because you can perform cross-database queries there, so you don't have to worry about it here.

Also, you can specify permissions on schemas in PostgreSQL, so you can control who gets to access the data in which schema, which should be enough to assuage your concerns about data separation.

Comment: how about manageability. Putting all the customers' data together may grow the size of database drastically. Won't it become cumbersome, if we want to restore the database in another server that has grown to some TBs. In case if they are separate databases, then the administration overhead will reduce, is that not true? can you please shed some lights on it.

Comment: I don't think that is true. With a `pg_dump`, you can backup and restore single schemas just as easily as single databases. With a file system backup like `pg_basebackup`, you can only backup the whole instance, not a dingle database.